# Fail2ban not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04, fail2ban

I'm trying to implement `fail2ban` on a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 server.  I've done the following:

`apt-get install fail2ban`

Made a copy of `jail.conf` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf.local` here's an excerpt:

```
[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime  = 600
maxretry = 3

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime  = 600
```

Then I ran `service fail2ban restart` and I do see it running.  Now I try to login as a user (root, random user, etc) multiple times in a row and it does not block my IP address.  I have `iptables` installed and it working with rules I have setup and I do have a `INPUT` chain in place of course.

When I cat `/var/log/auth.log` this is what I see

```
Oct 26 08:55:21 prod sshd[10935]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for firewall.jaincpa.com [75.89.97.25] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 26 08:55:23 prod sshd[10935]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:55:25 prod sshd[10935]: Failed password for root from 75.89.97.25 port 61449 ssh2
Oct 26 08:55:32  sshd[10935]: last message repeated 2 times
Oct 26 08:55:32 prod sshd[10935]: Connection closed by 75.89.97.25 [preauth]
Oct 26 08:55:32 prod sshd[10935]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:55:34 prod sshd[10944]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for firewall.jaincpa.com [75.89.97.25] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 26 08:55:35 prod sshd[10944]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:55:37 prod sshd[10944]: Failed password for root from 75.89.97.25 port 61452 ssh2
Oct 26 08:55:44  sshd[10944]: last message repeated 2 times
Oct 26 08:55:44 prod sshd[10944]: Connection closed by 75.89.97.25 [preauth]
Oct 26 08:55:44 prod sshd[10944]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:55:47 prod sshd[10951]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for firewall.jaincpa.com [75.89.97.25] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 26 08:55:51 prod sshd[10951]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:55:52 prod sshd[10951]: Failed password for root from 75.89.97.25 port 61455 ssh2
Oct 26 08:56:00  sshd[10951]: last message repeated 2 times
Oct 26 08:56:00 prod sshd[10951]: Connection closed by 75.89.97.25 [preauth]
Oct 26 08:56:00 prod sshd[10951]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:56:13 prod sshd[10971]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for firewall.jaincpa.com [75.89.97.25] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 26 08:56:15 prod sshd[10971]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:56:16 prod sshd[10971]: Failed password for root from 75.89.97.25 port 61459 ssh2
Oct 26 08:56:22  sshd[10971]: last message repeated 2 times
Oct 26 08:56:22 prod sshd[10971]: Connection closed by 75.89.97.25 [preauth]
Oct 26 08:56:22 prod sshd[10971]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=75.89.97.25  user=root
Oct 26 08:57:18 prod sshd[11002]: Connection closed by 50.116.16.93 [preauth]
Oct 26 09:00:01 prod CRON[11099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user deploy by (uid=0)
Oct 26 09:00:02 prod CRON[11099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user deploy
Oct 26 09:02:18 prod sshd[11186]: Connection closed by 50.116.16.93 [preauth]
root@prod:/etc/fail2ban#
```

So it looks like I'm authenticating with `PAM` via `sshd` but `fail2ban` is not blocking my IP address and I can still attempt login and login when supplying the proper credentials.

I'd like to get this working as I've seen a lot of brute force attacks on my server lately.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I needed to specify the backend to get this to working.  It was defaulting to `gamin` whih wasn't working.  I changed the configuration to `backend = polling` and got fail2ban working properly.  Haven't received any email notifications of blocking, but I'm close to figuring that out too.